# count occurrence of column in another column with awk

Tags: awk

How would you count occurrence of column 2 in column 1 with awk?

Input:

```
AA BB 
BB AA
BB CC
AA BB
CC AA
CC BB
CC CC
BB BB
```

Output:

```
AA BB 3
BB AA 2
BB CC 3
AA BB 3
CC AA 2
CC BB 3
CC CC 3
BB BB 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by this "ount occurrence of column2 in column1 with awk"?

Comment: and, welcome to S.O. In case you missed it, we're here to help you solve your problems with programming. Please include your attempts to solve this problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your example input, this gives the same output as you expected

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{print $0,a[$2]}' file file
AA BB 3
BB AA 2
BB CC 3
AA BB 3
CC AA 2
CC BB 3
CC CC 3
BB BB 3
```